# Alignment of characters in Word or Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, characters, alignment

I have some hyphenated data like this:

```
    A
1| 2-8
2| 0-12345
3| 15-123
4| and so on
```

How do I align the contents in word or excel such that hyphen is at the center?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is difficult to understand. Rows have multiple columns, of which you do not mention. Is all of your data in a single column? Please ***[edit]*** it to explain in better detail how the data is laid out. Also include what you are trying to accomplish and what you have already attempted.

Comment: In a Word table you do this with a centred tab, in Excel with a custom format.  The title of your question suggest you want both, is that true?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I wanted in either of them.

Comment: In Word, the ruler has a "Decimal Tab" alignment option. If you were willing to swap hyphens for decimal points, then that feature would achieve the effect ... but only in Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution for Excel

<sup>Assuming you are talking about centering text within a **single column** (and not a row)</sup>

#### You could use VBA to do 3 steps with one click

1. Set your cells to a font  with a fixed width like *Consolas*
2. Center your cells
3. Add spaces to the beginning or end of your string until the hyphen is centered

```vb
Sub CenterHyphenatedContent()
    For Each cell In UsedRange
        If InStr(cell.Value, "-") > 0 Then
                                    
            cell.Font.Name = "Consolas"
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            
            intLenLeft = InStrRev(cell.Value, "-") - 1
            intLenRight = Len(cell) - InStr(cell.Value, "-")
            intDiff = Abs(intLenLeft - intLenRight)
            
            If intLenLeft > intLenRight Then cell.Value = cell.Value & Space(intDiff)
            If intLenLeft < intLenRight Then cell.Value = Space(intDiff) & cell.Value

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Before & after

[image][image]

Attention: This code changes your Excel data since it adds extra spaces

Answer (score 1):

In Word I achieved something similar using tabs. For example, I wanted a series of rows to align on the multiplication symbol. To do this I put a right-aligned tab at 2 cm, a centre aligned tab at 2.25 cm and a left-aligned tab at 2.5 cm. Then the text on each row looked like:

> *TAB*"first text"*TAB*×*TAB*"second text"

[Example of Word text aligned on a character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yngCC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could put formulae into cols B and C that split the values of col A into the left-side and the right-side of the hyphen. e.g. using your example use `left()` to put "2" into B1 and `right()` to put "-32" into C1. Then right-justify col B, left-justify col C, and hide col A.

Comment: Yeah, tried this before. But it becomes a mess when I click on equally distribute rows and columns.